# dual-monitor and need to rearrange all programs through workspace Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

Using 8*8 workspaces with 2 monitors with several terminals (or any programs) opened, if I turned monitors off and on again, the locations of terminals are changed, so I need to check up all workspace and re-arrange them.

Any one has similar experiences and solved this problem?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you added the reboot tag.

Comment: mistake..........